# C++ State pattern exception

Tags: c++, design-patterns, state-pattern

I'm new in c++! 
Please help me to implement State pattern.

I have the code below, but it doesn't compile:

```
class MasterThreadState;
class Init; class Idle;

class MasterThread
{
public:
    MasterThread(){
        _state = Init::State();
    }
    void handle(int sender, int tag);
private:
    int _sender;
    MasterThreadState* _state;
private:
    friend class MasterThreadState;
    void goTo(MasterThreadState* newState){ _state = newState; }
};

class MasterThreadState
{
public:
    virtual void recieved(MasterThread& master, int tag);
protected:
    void goTo(MasterThread& m, MasterThreadState* newState){
        m.goTo(newState);
    }
};

class Init : MasterThreadState {
public:
    static MasterThreadState& State() { return instance; }
    virtual void recieved(MasterThread& master, int tag);
private:
    static Init instance;
};

class Idle : MasterThreadState {
public:
    void recieved(MasterThread& master,int tag);
    static MasterThreadState& State(){ return instance; }
private:
    static Idle instance;
};
```

The error is:

incomplete type 'Init' used in nested name specifier
     _state = Init::State();

Comment: You cannot use `Init` just with a forward declaration to be returned by value, use a pointer or a reference instead. You don't want to have a copy of the state anyway.

Comment: Thank you for reply, but can you show which piece of code I have to change?

Comment: place the definition of `MasterThread::MasterThread` after `Init` definition.

Comment: When I do this I caught error: undefined reference to `vtable for Init'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The virtual function wasn't implemented

This code work's fine:

```
class MasterThreadState;
class Init; //class Idle;

class MasterThread
{
public:
    MasterThread();
    void handle(int sender, int tag);
private:
    int _sender;
    MasterThreadState* _state;
private:
    friend class MasterThreadState;
    void goTo(MasterThreadState* newState){ _state = newState; }
};

class MasterThreadState
{
public:
    virtual void recieved(MasterThread& master, int tag) = 0;
protected:
    void goTo(MasterThread& m, MasterThreadState* newState){
        m.goTo(newState);
    }
};

class Init : MasterThreadState {
public:
    static MasterThreadState* State();
    virtual void recieved(MasterThread& master, int tag);
private:
    Init(){}
};

class Idle : MasterThreadState {
public:
    static MasterThreadState* State();
    virtual void recieved(MasterThread& master,int tag);
private:
    static Idle instance;
};
```

Comment: An unimplemented function can cause a linker error, not a compiler error. What fixed it is defining `MasterThread::MasterThread()` out-of line, where the full declaration of `Init` was accessible.

Answer (score 0):

If move MasterThread constructor after Init declaration, the code will compile (and, build):

```
class MasterThread
{
public:
    MasterThread();
    void handle(int sender, int tag);
private:
    int _sender;
    MasterThreadState* _state;
private:
    friend class MasterThreadState;
    void goTo(MasterThreadState* newState){ _state = newState; }
};

class MasterThreadState
{
public:
    virtual void recieved(MasterThread& master, int tag) {}
protected:
    void goTo(MasterThread& m, MasterThreadState* newState){
        m.goTo(newState);
    }
};

class Init : MasterThreadState {
public:
    static MasterThreadState* State() { return &instance; }
    virtual void recieved(MasterThread& master, int tag) {}
private:
    static Init instance;
};

Init Init::instance;

MasterThread::MasterThread() {
    _state = Init::State();
}
```

Notice, that Init::State() should return pointer, `MasterThreadState*`. This was also changed, static member Init::instance defined, and implementation (empty) of virtual functions added to link properly.